# Mongo DB mapReduce() : E QUERY [js] TypeError: c.out is undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

When I call `mapReduce`:

```js
// the body of the map and reduce function is not important, suppose we already defined it
db.my_collection.mapReduce(map, reduce,{})
```

I get a error:

```
2019-12-11T09:58:05.492+0800 E QUERY    [js] TypeError: c.out is undefined :
DBCollection.prototype.mapReduce@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1135:1
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify something for `out`, either a collection name or inline

```
db.active_user_behavior.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: { inline:1 } })
```